# What computer display technology is used in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, technology, computers

What kind of computer technology do they use in The Force Awakens? I am trying to remember if they showed footage of computers in any of the command-base scenes or anything.

Comment: hmm, can't really recall either. The Millenium Falcon is probably still using the same tech as it did 30 years ago. The ship Han was on contained monitor screens displaying CCTV feeds. And of course Starkiller Base used at least one hologram display for portraying tactical readouts like the Death Star plans they just happen to carry around everywhere in case people build another one

Answer (score 2):

Keeping in line with the Original Trilogy, Star Wars: The Force Awakens makes use of two types of main displays; holograms and screens. In Leia Organa's Resistance Base, the predominant color seems to be teal/green. Displays on planets and ship movements seem to be concentrated on hologram tables, whereas other displays show typical readouts such as energy and other statistics.

[image]

In contrast, the First Order focuses a lot more on red, orange and blue screen displays throughout *Star Killer* base and other ships. TIE Fighters still use the same general design as that used in the first films.